# Elementary number theory( divisor)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If $n= 2009$, then $A=2009^n-1982^n-1972^n+1945^n$ is **NOT** divisible by..

1. 659
2. 1977
3. 1998
4. 2009

Please someone let me know how to solve these kind of problems.

Comment: Which tools do you have at your disposal here? In particular, can you find the prime factorizations of the proposed divisors?

Comment: If you give some context and/or show what you have tried then the question may be able to be reopened (so you may get further answers, and it will help prevent the question from being deleted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Both $\,659\,$ and $\,1977 = 3\cdot 659\,$ *are* divisors of $A\,$ since

$$ 2009+1945 = 6\cdot659 = 1982+1972$$

so the paired summands are negatives of each other mod $659$ and $3\cdot 659\,$ so cancel out in $A$, i.e.

$\quad \begin{align}\color{#0a0}{2009\equiv -1945}\\ \color{#c00}{1982\equiv -1972}\end{align}$ $\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ $  $\begin{align} &\quad\ \color{#0a0}{2009}^n\ +1945^n -\quad\,\color{#c00}{1982}^n\ -\ 1972^n\\
\equiv\ &(\color{#0a0}{-1945})^n+1945^n-(\color{#c00}{-1972})^n-1972^n\equiv\, 0\ {\rm\ by\ n\ odd}\end{align}$

Similarly, rearranging the first equations, we get cancelling pairs of terms mod $27$ and $37$

$$\begin{align} 
2009-1982=27 = 1972-1945\\
2009-1972=37 = 1982-1942\end{align}$$

So $27$ and $37$ divisors of $A\,$ and by parity $2$ is too, thus so is their product $\,2\cdot 27\cdot 37 = 1998$.

That leaves $\,2009\,$ (choice $4)$ as the only possible nondivisor.

---

**Remark** $\ $ Abstracting the above argument immediately yields the following

**Theorem** $\ $ If $\ a,b,c,d\,$ are integers such that $\ a+b+c+d=0\,$ and $\,f(x)\,$ is an odd polynomial with integer coefficients then $\,f(a)+f(b)+f(c)+f(d)\,$ is divisible by $\,a+b,\, a+c,\, a+d$.

Above is the special case $\, f(x) = x^{\large 2009},\, $ and $\ a,b,c,d\, =\, 2009,-1982,-1972,1945$.

Comment: See also [these answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+polynomial+symmetric+multi) for more on the innate symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

We have $1945\equiv -2009 \pmod {1977}$ and $1972\equiv -1982 \pmod {1977} .$

If $x\equiv -y \pmod z$, and $n$ is odd, then $x^n\equiv -y^n \pmod z.$ That is, $x^n+y^n\equiv 0\pmod z.$

So $2009^n+1945^n$ and $1982^n+1972^n$  are both divisible by $1977.$ Since $1977=(3)(659) $, they are both divisible by $659$ too.

Sorry I'm too tired right now to say more.

Answer (score 0):

The best method I can think of is educated trial-and-error.

Let's try $659$.
$$2009^n - 1982^n - 1972^n + 1945^n \equiv 32^n - 5^n - (-5)^n + (-32)^n \pmod{659}$$
which, for odd $n$ like $2009$, is obviously $0$.

What about $1977$? Well, $1977 = 659 \times 3$ and a little more observation about the sizes of the numbers will tell us that the above equivalence is the same.

$1998$? $$2009^n - 1982^n - 1972^n + 1945^n \equiv 11^n - (-16)^n - (-26)^n + (-53)^n \pmod{1998}$$ This seems like a candidate, we'll come back to it later.

$2009$? Well, a hint here is that $n = 2009$ too. We can factorize $2009  = 7^2 \times 41$ and by Fermat's Little Theorem, we know $41$ divides the expression; we now have
$$2009^n - 1982^n - 1972^n + 1945^n \equiv - 22^n - 12^n + 34^n \pmod{49}$$

Since this is a multiple choice-question, I would leave this here because it looks like the congruence will be $0$ only when $n$ is $1$ or something similar (check out Euler's Totient Theorem), and choose $2009$.

Comment: Hint for $\,1998\!:\,$ notice: $\ 2009-1982 = 27 = 1972 - 1945\ $ so $\ 27\mid A.\,$ Further $\,\gcd(27,1998) = 27.\ $  See my answer for more on the innate symmetry.